# Drawer Navigator nested inside Bottom Navigator

Tags: react-navigation

Is it possible to nest a drawer inside my bottom Navigator?
I managed to have the opposite. I have a drawer that has a screen my bottom nav.
But when I change to another drawer screen, I lose my bottom navigator. I want my bottom navigator to be global with a hamburger menu as my drawer.